# Secured Linked Server!

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssms, linked-server

following some tutorials i've succeded to create a linked service from a Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to Oracle,  i've followed another [tutorial](https://kb.berkeley.edu/jivekb/entry.jspa?externalID=1005) in order to make the connection encrypted, this was a piece of cake, i checked the oracles trace files it showed that it's using encryption, but when i query from MSSMS the trace files ain't generated and i can't check whether it use encryption or not!!

so any idea to check if my linked server is secure enough?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resolved something was missing in my client computer sqlnet.ora config!

Comment: If you're going to post this as an answer, it would be beneficial to document what the "something" was.

Comment: well the tutorial in the link above explain everything, my error was simple, i have configured the sqlnet.ora on the database server machine instead of the client machine..